# Best practice for adding data to a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to add a static amount of data from a csv file into a postgresql database that im hosting on Heroku.

Initially, I was doing this programmatically in my application.py file, which was serving the web server with flask. I'm interacting with the database using SQLalchemy

Basically, I have this block of code where I'm committing data to my database before I'm handling routes.

```
for el in books:
   db.execute("INSERT INTO books (isbn, title) VALUES (:isbn, :title)",
             {"isbn": el[0], "title": el[1]})
   db.commit
```

I think that the biggest problem with doing this is the web server is that I'm commiting the same data each time I restart my web server. Does anyone have advice for the best way that I should be doing this process?

Comment: Does the data in the CSV ever change?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the data in the CSV never changes. It's just 5000 entries in a format that I know how to parse already.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Tov suggested something below, but it still doesn't really get around the fact that I'd be checking EACH time i restart the web server to see changes. There has to be a better way where we could just do this once? I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

You write: "I'm commiting the same data each time I restart my web server".

A database stores the data persistently, meaning the data stays in your database (an exception is an in-memory-db, but even this kind of dbms allows for storing the data on disk).

In result, after you have run your code n times, the data should be in there n times (assuming that you are not also dropping an creating the table each time).

You can easily check that, e.g. by counting the isbn occurrences:

```
select count(isbn) as c, isbn from books group by isbn order by c desc;
```

Assuming in the `csv` each isbn is unique, all the count values should be `1`, but in your case it is rather `n`.

So clean your table and do the import once. Insert only new data, update only existing, changed data.

Comment: So, I just need to do a simple check for that books ID before I try to insert it into the database again? I think you're right about the data being in there n times that's what I meant.

Comment: Yes, if you want to check if a book is already in the table you could check for the ISBN before you insert it.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that because the data doesn't change I could just use sql's COPY command.

After starting the command line with `psql DATABASE_URL` I was able to `TRUNCATE` the table to delete everything in it and then I just did:

`\copy books(column_name_1, column_name_2,...) from 'path/to/csv' delimiter ',' csv header;`

the delimiter is how your field values are separated in the csv header and the csv header option tells sql what the breakdown of the csv file is. In my case the csv header was the first line, which sql ignores with the csv header option, it looked like this:

`isbn,title,author,year`

Thanks to everyone that responded.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the CSV never changes then \copy it into the database once outside the application and then drop the code that does that on start up. If you anticipate that there might be changes in the future then have code that you can trigger from either inside the application(in admin section if that exists) or outside. What that code does would be dependent on what the changes would be. If the changes are just adding or deleting complete entries then you could get by with something like(pseudo code):

```
CREATE TEMP table data_staging(fields to match CSV);
\copy data_staging FROM  csv_file
--INSERT new items
INSERT INTO books() SELECT * from data_staging AS ds  LEFT JOIN books ON ds.isbn = books.isbn WHERE books.isbn IS NULL;
--If you want to DELETE
INSERT INTO books() SELECT * FROM books LEFT JOIN  data_staging AS ds    ON books.isbn = ds.isbn WHERE ds.isbn IS NULL;
```

UPDATEing rows would require more work as you would need to walk over the records and see if there are any changes between those in the staging table and the books table.